# output issue with command line

Tags: php

main.php

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
require_once('./TController.php');

TController::doMain($argc, $argv);

return 0;
?>
```

TController.php

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/A.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../B.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../C.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/D.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/E.php");
class TController
{
    public function doMain($argc, $argv)
    {
        StockPriceDefiner::defineStock();

        if($argc != 10) {
            $file = "main.php";
            echo <<<EOT
usage:
php $file year month day width 500 ana_ana isDiv

ex):
input parameters
EOT;
            return;
        }
        print_r($argv); 
    }
}
?>
```

I have tried to `php main.php [enter]` from the command prompt but the usage above isn't displayed. is there anything incorrect you can spot, please help me.

[**UPDATE**]
there is no error, just nothing is displayed.

Comment: Is this literally the unabridged content of your `TController.php`? Then it's invalid syntax. You're missing a `class` declaration.

Comment: does it outputs correctly without command-line?

Comment: @linuxeasy, how can i do that, my program is at present meant to run from a shell or command prompt

Comment: @Darcy try using `php main.php a b c d f e` as argv is intended to show arguments. Also please enable error reporting by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of the code.

Comment: @Darcy also please note that your TController file doesn't have TravelJpController::doMain definition (either class or function)

Comment: `TController::doMain($argc, $argv);` is an error because `doMain` method is not declared as `static`

Answer (score 0):

Please enable error report by adding

```
error_report(E_ALL);
```

at the start of your main.php file.

Secondly, if TController.php file is all you have pasted, then it certainly doesn't contain any definition of

```
TravelJpController::doMain()
```

This should do the trick:

```
TController::doMain($argc, $argv);
```